# #snmp RamSize OID and RamUsed OID

Tags: c#-3.0, snmp, net-snmp

Anyone can tell me OIDs to get the values of ram size and ram used. 
as this link http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=nvRamSize&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true 
I try to get values of this OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.3.6.7 butn it's not return values.
Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: No SNMP agent implements all available objects. They only implement what is meaningful for their purposes. In your case, it seems this agent simply does not have such an object defined.

Comment: thank for your reply.